# microsoft-teams: How can we update the app of all users ? Lack of functionality plus issue

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.

And we are updating valid domains list from time to time (Adding new valid domains).
So we have to be sure that all users have latest version of the app.
If someone has old version of the app (without this valid domain name) they will not be able to open that site in task module window.
It is very important to keep the app updated.

So as we expected users are experiencing issues with valid domain names.
And the simple question "which app version does user have" led us to next issues: lack of a basic functionality on Mobile versions of the Teams app and a bug on the Desktop/Browser versions of the Teams app.

Mobile apps: There's just no way of getting app version. Or at least we haven't found it.
Desktop/Browser apps: There's 'About' tab with the description of the app and it's version. But in our case the text is long and the section is not scrollable so users can't scroll up and get app version. Check the screenshot below

Is there a way of updating the app for all our users of all tenants ?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Desktop/Browser Screenshot]

Comment: For anyone on the MS team looking at this, it's an excellent point raised about understanding the upgrade process for a store app in general. If the app is in the store, does it auto-update when a new version is released, or does the user need to trigger it somehow (if so, I've not seen that).

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Yeah, there's an 'Upgrade' button. But it appears only in Browser/Desktop Apps and it's a bit random. Sometimes we see 'Upgrade' button sometimes we don't.
But i've never seen the upgrade button in mobile apps.

Answer (score 3):

@Oleksa, @Hilton - Process of updating the version of the app is similar to how you submit the app initially to store.

Teams does not force users to update to latest available version of the App but it shows small banner with the message "latest version of the app is available" which user has to go and update to the newer version.

[image]

I am surprised, @Hilton did not have this question till now :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Abhijit.
One more question: Do mobile apps have this functionality (Upgrade button) ?

Comment: yeah, funny I've not needed to think about it so far :-). Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Oleksa, Yes, it works for mobile as well. 
If it answers your query please accept this answer.

Comment: Hi @Abhijit-MSFT thanks for the reply. Unfortunately no, i can't see anywhere the "Upgrade" button on mobile devices. I had to remove Teams and reinstall it to get latest version of our app on my mobile device.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT also there's no way of checking app version so i had to test everything manually to understand what app version i have which is frustrating and we cant advice our clients to do the same.

Comment: @Oleksa, Did you submit the new version to store and then checked?

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT Yes we did. So as i said i had to wipe Teams and Install it again to get latest version of our app. It seems like it was cached somewhere and there's no way to know whether you have latest version of the app or not

Comment: @Oleksa, Let me try this out

Comment: Hi @Abhijit-MSFT have you tried this out ?

Comment: @Oleksa, is this issue resolved or is it pending? If it is let me take this to internal team to discuss.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT Hi Manish. Yes it is pending, unfortunately nothing has changed regards that. Please do. Thank you.

Comment: @Oleksa, I just received a reply from engineering team according to them. You can only upgrade an app on desktop and not on mobile. Upgrading the app on desktop will automatically do the same on mobile. Are you still not able to see updated app on mobile after updating it on desktop?

Comment: @Manish-MSFT Thank you for your effort. I wiped the app from the phone and reinstalled. That helped. But most our users use mobile devices only.
Am i understood correctly users can't update a bot app without the desktop version of the Teams app?

Comment: @Oleksa, Yes, for now users have to update the app from the desktop version only. The upgrade process from other devices is in pipeline but we don't specific ETA to be shared. I hope this information helps you.

Comment: is it possible to update a user/team installed app via Graph ?
there are calls to add / remove an app in these scopes, would re-adding the app force an update ?

Comment: Just a note. The message that there is a updated version of the app only shows when viewing the personal tab.  If viewing the app within a team there is no indication that there exists an update to the app.  Only way to see that is by going to "Manage Team" > Apps

Answer (score 0):

As of (19/1/2021), You can only upgrade an app on desktop and not on mobile. Upgrading the app on desktop will automatically do the same on mobile.

Comment: If you upgrade the app in the personal tab then you also have to go through all the teams and update them there as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355189/team-teamid-installedapps-expanded-with-teamsappdefinition-showing-the-incorre/65607484?noredirect=1#comment116516797_65607484