# team/{teamid}/installedApps expanded with teamsAppDefinition showing the incorrect version

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I was thinking of using Microsoft Graph API to get the version number of an installed app within that team.
Documentation suggests calling /team/{teamid}/installedApps for that. [Documentation (List apps in team)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-list-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

My issue is that teamsAppDefinition contains the version number but it does not match the installed version on the team but rather what the version is in the store.

Team app version should be: 1.3.2
The store app version is: 1.3.3

My request is like this:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/installedApps?$expand=teamsApp,teamsAppDefinition](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7BteamId%7D/installedApps?$expand=teamsApp,teamsAppDefinition)
Returns:

```
"teamsAppDefinition": {
        "id": "MzYxZWU4MjItZTAyMC00ZTA2LWFmYjUtNzFlNjBhODVmZDUzIyMxLjMuMw==",
        "teamsAppId": "{teamsAppId}",
        "displayName": "{AppName}",
        "version": "1.3.3"
}
```

When going to the team within Microsoft Teams and go into "Manage Team" I can see that it the app needs updating so it's not the same version as the latest one.

Regards,
Oskar

Comment: Looks like this is a very though question as I've yet to get any response :/

Comment: Please try to uninstall the existing app in personal and in channel if any and try to re-install.

Comment: Deleting the app/uninstalling will remove it from all Teams yes. But that is not what I'm after since this is a issue for our customers.  So I need to be able to get the correct installed app version on the Team, and not just what is installed on the Tenant.
See my comment to RB-2902's answer.

Comment: I suggest also checking out :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240611/microsoft-teams-how-can-we-update-the-app-of-all-users-lack-of-functionality/65249210

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce the issue with my Teams App, but was unable to find a single mismatch in the versions of the Team App and the Store app, for any of the installed apps. It might be that my apps are all updated, hence unable to reproduce. I am still trying to repro it in other machines with old updates. Will keep you posted, once we reproduce the issue on our end.
Thank you :).

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The issue can be seen when edting a Team and go to the App tab.  There will be a message saying that there is a new version of the app available and offering you update it by clicking on it in the list.
When querying this Team with the Graph API endpoints mentioned above you will get the version of the app that is in the store.  Not whatever version is installed on the Team.

Comment: Hi @Oskar, Thank you so much for describing the steps to repro. Let me try the same and update you soon.

Comment: Hi @Oskar Jensson Fjeld, I did repro the steps described and was unable to find mismatch in the versions of the Team App and the Store app, for any of the installed apps.

Comment: Well the point is that I can't get the correct version number from the endpoints but I know the version is not what I get back as I can see it asking me to update the app when viewing the Manage Team/Apps page